# How to compare tables and find duplicates and also find columns with different value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following tables in Oracle 10g:

```
Table1
Name  Status
a         closed
b         live
c         live

Table2
Name  Status
a         final
b         live
c         live
```

There are no primary keys in both tables, and I am trying to write a query which will return identical rows without looping both tables and comparing rows/columns. If the status column is different then the row in the Table2 takes presedence.

So in the above example my query should return this:

```
Name   Status
a         final
b         live
c         live
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that there are no *Primary Key* on both tables, I'm assuming that there maybe a possibility that a row may exist on `Table1`, `Table2`, or both. The query below uses `Common Table Expression` and `Windowing function` to get such result.

```
WITH unionTable
AS
(
    SELECT  Name, Status, 1 AS ordr FROM Table1
    UNION 
    SELECT  Name, Status, 2 AS ordr FROM Table2
),
ranks 
AS
(
    SELECT  Name, Status,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ordr DESC) rn
    FROM    unionTable
)
SELECT  Name, Status
FROM    ranks
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2faf4/4)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT table1.Name, table2.Status
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Name = table2.Name
```

By always returning `table2.Status` you've covered both the case when they're the same and when they're different (essentially it doesn't matter what the value of `table1.Status` is).